# DynamoDB table gets partially updated

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, runtime-error, amazon-dynamodb

When trying to update DynamoDB table only the partition key value gets updated. While trying to include the rest of the values the following error pops up. Pointing to the getter methods.

```
import android.util.Log;
import com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException;
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBHashKey;
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBMapper;
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBTable;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.DescribeTableRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.DescribeTableResult;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ResourceNotFoundException;

public class FeedbackDynamoDBManager {

private static final String TAG = "FeedbackDynamoDBManager";


public static String getTestTableStatus() {

    try {
        AmazonDynamoDBClient ddb = FeedbackActivity.clientManager
                .ddb();

        DescribeTableRequest request = new DescribeTableRequest()
                .withTableName(Constants.FEEDBACK_TABLE);
        DescribeTableResult result = ddb.describeTable(request);

        String status = result.getTable().getTableStatus();
        return status == null ? "" : status;

    } catch (ResourceNotFoundException e) {
    } catch (AmazonServiceException ex) {
        FeedbackActivity.clientManager
                .wipeCredentialsOnAuthError(ex);
    }
    return "";
}


public static void insertFeedback(FeedbackForm feedbackForm) {
    AmazonDynamoDBClient fdb = FeedbackActivity.clientManager
            .ddb();
    DynamoDBMapper fMapper = new DynamoDBMapper(fdb);

    try {
        Log.d(TAG, "Inserting form");
        fMapper.save(feedbackForm);
        Log.d(TAG, "Form inserted");
    } catch (AmazonServiceException ex) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error inserting form");
        ex.printStackTrace();
        FeedbackActivity.clientManager
                .wipeCredentialsOnAuthError(ex);
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("Feedback Form: ",e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@DynamoDBTable(tableName = Constants.FEEDBACK_TABLE)
public static class FeedbackForm {
        private String formId;
        private String bus;
        private String comments;
        private String ended_at;
        private String route;
        private String started_from;
        private String travel_date;

        @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "form_id")
        public String getFormId() {
            return formId;
        }
        public void setFormId(String formId) {
            this.formId = formId;
        }

        @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "bus")
        public String getBus() {
            return bus;
        }
        public void setBus(String bus) {
            this.bus = bus;
        }

        @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "comments")
        public String getComments() {
            return comments;
        }
        public void setComments(String comments) {
            this.comments = comments;
        }

        @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "ended_at")
        public String getEndedAt() {
            return ended_at;
        }
        public void setEndedAt(String ended_at) {
            this.ended_at = ended_at;
        }

        @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "route")
        public String getRoute() {
            return route;
        }
        public void setRoute(String route) {
            this.route = route;
        }

        @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "started_from")
        public String getStartedFrom() {
            return started_from;
        }
        public void setStartedFrom(String started_from) {
            this.started_from = started_from;
        }

        @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "travel_date")
        public String getTraveDate() {
            return travel_date;
        }
        public void setTraveDate(String travel_date) {
            this.travel_date = travel_date;
        }

    }
}
```

FeedbackDynamoDBManager.java

```
    FeedbackDynamoDBManager.FeedbackForm feedbackForm = new FeedbackDynamoDBManager.FeedbackForm();

feedbackForm.setFormId(formId);
feedbackForm.setTraveDate(selectedDate);
feedbackForm.setComments(comments);
feedbackForm.setRoute(selectedRoute);
feedbackForm.setBus(selectedBus);
feedbackForm.setEndedAt(selectedEndLocation);
feedbackForm.setStartedFrom(selectedFromLocation);
FeedbackDynamoDBManager.insertFeedback(feedbackForm);
```

FeedbackActivity.java

```
03-15 14:39:47.040 11788-12278/com.iota.bus.institutebus E/AmazonClientManager: Error, wipeCredentialsOnAuthError calledcom.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: The provided key element does not match the schema (Service: AmazonDynamoDB; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: 999LSFAJHJS999999D372C3LVVV4KQNSO5A99999999ASUAAJG)
E/FEEDBACK FORM: Data inserted!!!

  [03-15 14:39:47.104  4531: 4531 E/         ]
  [adb] handle_packet() t->online(1) p->msg.arg0(30963) p->msg.arg1(0) OPEN
  [ 03-15 14:39:47.104  4531: 4531 E/         ]
  [adb] handle the adb command, and the command = adb shell:cat /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/stats | grep 10369
  [ 03-15 14:39:47.132  4531: 4531 E/         ]
  [adb] cuurent command is A_CLSE 
  [ 03-15 14:39:47.412  4531: 4531 E/         ]
  [adb] handle_packet() t->online(1) p->msg.arg0(30964) p->msg.arg1(0) OPEN
  [ 03-15 14:39:47.412  4531: 4531 E/         ]
  [adb] handle the adb command, and the command = adb shell:cat /proc/11788/stat
  [ 03-15 14:39:47.430  4531: 4531 E/         ]
  [adb] cuurent command is A_CLSE 
  [ 03-15 14:39:47.450  4531: 4531 E/         ]
  [adb] handle_packet() t->online(1) p->msg.arg0(30965) p->msg.arg1(0) OPEN
  [ 03-15 14:39:47.450  4531: 4531 E/         ]
  [adb] handle the adb command, and the command = adb shell:cat /proc/stat
  [ 03-15 14:39:47.467  4531: 4531 E/         ]
  [adb] cuurent command is A_CLSE 
  [ 03-15 14:39:47.642  4531: 4531 E/         ]
  [adb] handle_packet() t->online(1) p->msg.arg0(30966) p->msg.arg1(0) OPEN
  [ 03-15 14:39:47.642  4531: 4531 E/         ]
  [adb] handle the adb command, and the command = adb shell:cat /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/stats | grep 10369
  [ 03-15 14:39:47.669  4531: 4531 E/         ]
  [adb] cuurent command is A_CLSE
```

logcat

I dont have a lot of experience posting in stackoverflow. Please be lenient :).

EDIT: When commenting out getters other than that of form_id. The data gets updated. Otherwise the logcat error shows.

[AWS console DynamoDB table screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/laHdk.png)

Comment: Please show the code and explain the expected result

Comment: @notionquest Hopefully this is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is on `FeedbackForm` class. All the attributes are defined with annotation `@DynamoDBHashKey`. Please change the annotation as mentioned below for **non hash key fields**. You should use `@DynamoDBAttribute` for normal attributes.

```
@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "comments")
        public String getComments() {
            return comments;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this resolved my problem. I copy pasted and din't realize.